# Non-zero exit status 139 due to free() statement for a memory pointer

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

In the below attached code I am re-encrypting a file by opening, reading the contents into a buffer, re-encrypting the buffer with a new key and then writing back to the file.

The program is being run as a subprocess in a python/django based server. which prints the error output as: `*** Error in`/home/kunal/Documents/MyCrest/cloud/backend/mainbgw': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000ecc250 ***`

The last statement `free(ciphertext)` to clean up the allocated memory gives me error sometimes where the program exits with a status code of 139 i.e `double free or corruption` If I remove that statement then the code works perfectly, but I would like return from the function the right way by freeing up the allocated memory.

```
int update_encryption(char *fileName, char *base_k1, char *base_k1_new, const char* privateKey)
{
  FILE *file;
  size_t cipherlen,keylen;
  unsigned char *ciphertext,*k1_temp,*k1_new_temp,*k1,*k1_new;

  //read ciphertext from the file to be updated
  file = fopen(fileName,"rb");  //open in read binary stream mode
  if (file)
  {
    fseek (file, 0, SEEK_END);
    cipherlen = ftell (file);
    fseek (file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    ciphertext = (unsigned char*) malloc(cipherlen*sizeof(unsigned char));
    if (ciphertext)
    {
      fread (ciphertext, sizeof(unsigned char), cipherlen, file);
    }
    fclose (file);
  }

  //decrypt the data
  if(!Base64Decode(base_k1, &k1_temp, &keylen))
  {
    k1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*374);
    keylen = private_decrypt(k1_temp,keylen,(unsigned char *)privateKey, k1);
    k1[keylen]='\0';
    shaCrypt(ciphertext,(int)cipherlen, (const char *)k1, keylen);
    free(k1_temp);
    free(k1);
  }
  else
    return 1;

  //re-encrypt the data
  if(!Base64Decode(base_k1_new,&k1_new_temp,&keylen))
  {
    k1_new = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*374);
    keylen = private_decrypt(k1_temp,keylen,(unsigned char *)privateKey, k1_new);
    k1_new[keylen]='\0';
    shaCrypt(ciphertext,(int)cipherlen,(const char*)k1_new, keylen);
    free(k1_new_temp);
    free(k1_new);
  }
  else
    return 1;

  //write the encrypted data to file
  file = fopen(fileName,"wb");
  if (file)
  {
    fwrite(ciphertext, sizeof(unsigned char), cipherlen, file);
    fclose(file);
  }
  else
    return 1;

  //free memory for ciphertext
  if(ciphertext)
    free(ciphertext);
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
The error occurs only for files with size 3kB or more, since 139 is the error code for memory corruption OR double free, I guess it is the former case as there is nowhere where I am freeing a memory location twice in my code.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need the check `if(ciphertext)` before `free()`ing. It's valid to pass a NULL pointer to `free()`. :-)

Comment: You have `if(ciphertext)` but `ciphertext` is not initialized to 0, so if the first `if` block isn't entered, you're going to pass an invalid pointer to free.

Comment: Also, I see you did check for `maloc()` success, good, but what is it failed? That case should be handled first..

Comment: Yeah I know, the if statement has got nothing to do with that, I had just put it as a check for, in case the malloc fails but nope the problem is not due to that

Comment: @nemetroid Its is not initialized to `0`, it's NULL.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, the malloc isn't failing though, the file is being written correctly as expected

Comment: @bawejakunal [Don't be so sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I can spot memory leak, but not double free in the code. There are 3 "return 1" that could cause the function exit without releasing ciphertext.

Comment: If the file can't be opened properly, `ciphertext` will never be allocated. Since it's also not set to NULL, it will point to a random memory location and `free(ciphertext)` will crash.

Comment: And as always, [please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Comment: Could you provide a main function that uses the above function with just enough data that it reproduces the crash? I.e., a minimal self-contained example.

Comment: You did `#include <stdlib.h>`, right?

Comment: @simon thanks for pointing those out, fixed them now but the problem still persists, I added NULL as well as as evert suggested but no help on that end either, the program still exits with 139 or sometimes 134

Comment: @Evert yeah I did include stdlib else nothing would have worked :-/

Comment: What is the signature of shaCrpt? it looks suspicious to me. Does it change the ciphertext by any chance?

Comment: @simon it's part of a ongoing work so sorry I can't post a lot of code on the public forum, shaCrypt is a function to xor the bytes of ciphertext in chunks of 20 bytes with different SHA1 digests, it modifies the ciphertext string in place so no malloc or free in that function.

Comment: A simple test will be to comment out or mock the function body of shaCript to see if you error still remain.

Answer (score 2):

If the file can't be opened properly, ciphertext will never be allocated. Since it's also not set to NULL, it will point to a random memory location and free(ciphertext) will crash.

Set `ciphertext = NULL` near you declarations.

Comment: That changed the exit status from 139 to 134.

Comment: 134 could be "assertion failed". Does it come with an error message?

Comment: It is failing for file sizes above 3kB with error codes 139, do you think that could be causing memory overflow or something like that since 139 is for double free OR memory corruption ?